# DocumentDB: Query with 'array_contains' with an array?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

How is it possible to make the following query with DocumentDB:

```
var categoryID = '1,2,3,4,5';

SELECT * FROM products doc WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(doc._sort.category, ' + categoryID + ');
```

This clearly does not work.

Comment: ' + categoryID + ' is a string literal and won't even reference the variable. I suspect that's not all that is wrong but would need to see an example document to help more.

Comment: Right - in your example, `categoryID` isn't ever used. The only way this query would work is if your `_sort.category` property were an array, and it contained an element **" + categoryID + "**.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS([1,2,3,4,5], product.category)
```

Which can also be parameterized:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(@categoryIDs, product.category)
```

Where @categoryIDs = [1,2,3,4,5].

In .NET, here's a snippet:

```
Uri collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("testdb", "testcollsingle");
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

SqlQuerySpec query = new SqlQuerySpec(
    "SELECT VALUE ARRAY_CONTAINS(@categoryIds, 1)", 
    new SqlParameterCollection(new SqlParameter[] { 
        new SqlParameter { Name = "@categoryIds", Value = array 
}}));

bool result = client.CreateDocumentQuery<bool>(collectionUri, query)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn782250.aspx#bk_array_contains

Comment: I posted a more complete example with client code. Can you please try that?

Comment: Thank you, but still this does not work. The statement `WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(3, doc._filter.category)` does not work, and neither `WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS([3,6], doc._filter.category)` nor `WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(doc._filter.category, [3,6])` works ... just `WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(doc._filter.category, 3)` works as expected, but does not fulfill my needs :/

Comment: Can you please post a full repro with client code, documents, and expected/actual results?